# Summer' 16 Email-to-Case issue when attempting to change the ParentId on before email insert trigger

Tags: email2case, summer-16

Currently experience a Summer' 16 Email-to-Case issue when attempting to change the ParentId on before email insert trigger.

**Error Message:**

> INVALID_OPERATION : The specified **`Parent`** and **`RelatedTo`** conflict.

Link below is to a known issue with the workaround that does not work if you do not have enhanced email enabled.

Is anyone else having this issue or has more information? We are currently chasing Salesforce support for more details. I recommend testing your email-to-case functionality in your Summer'16 sandboxes.

Known Issue:
["The specified Parent and RelatedTo conflict" error when changing Parent Id of an EmailMessage in Summer'16](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jksmQAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, this is a known issue which means a bug has already been filed on the Salesforce side.

Note: [Safe Harbor applies to the below](http://investor.salesforce.com/about-us/investor/forward-looking-statements/)

I work in R&D at Salesforce and our current plan is to include a fix for this bug in today's weekly patch. To check if your instance has received the latest patch, you can check Trust with your instance. If your release version is "Summer '16 Patch 8" it should include that fix. A sample URL where you can check the version of an instance is as follows

http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/instances/CS4

This of course is subject to change, and not guaranteed, but that's the current plan.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I can confirm we did not experience any issues in Live since the release.